# safexl - A Python / pywin32 Excel Application wrapper

Tags: python, excel, windows, wrapper

Thanks in advance for your interest in my first PyPI project.

While there happen to be a number of projects out there to help with creating & consuming Excel workbooks, I was unable to find one that made working with pywin32 any easier, so I built it myself. Using pywin32 for automating Excel with best practices happens to require a lot of boilerplate code, and I wanted a project I could call on later once I've filled my brain with more useful things.

My main concerns at this time can be found in the following function. Specifically I'm interested in fresh perspectives on the style I used and my implementation.

```
def kill_all_instances_of_excel(app: 'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")' = None) -> None:
    """
    Simple wrapper around `psutil.process_iter()` searching for individual processes of EXCEL.EXE, and killing each one it finds
    :param app: Optional win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") - Programmatic access to Excel application object
    :return: None
    """
    if app:
        # If application is passed, try to shut it down peacefully first
        close_workbooks(app, app.Workbooks)
        app.Quit()
        del app

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == EXCEL_PROCESS_NAME:
                proc.kill()
        except (psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.NoSuchProcess):
            # passing on psutil.NoSuchProcess avoids erroring out if race conditions
            # close Excel *between* finding it and killing it with psutil
            pass
```

*To see this function in context you can:*

- *Look at the bottom of this post, where I'll paste the entire module needed to run the code*
- *Check it out on [GitHub](https://github.com/ThePoetCoder/safexl)*
- *Download it directly with* `pip install safexl`

**Style Questions**

I like using type hints, especially in projects that others will consume, as I think it really helps indicate the goal of a piece of code. But in this case, where I'm wrapping a COM object, I ended up writing `'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")'` a number of times for my type hints. For an added headache, note the use of single quotes book-ending the code here, which I added after I noticed that either python or win32com will sometimes execute this code placed in a type hint (especially in places where I'm returning the app, after a `->`)!

It seems like there's got to be a much simpler way to accomplish a specific type hint like this, but at this point the options I'm aware of are:

1. What I chose, a string of the code needed to create the COM object to be passed as an argument
2. A generic `object` type hint that isn't very explicit
3. No type hint at all

I went with the 1st option consistently.

**Implementation Questions**

In the event a COM application is passed, I try to shut it down peacefully at first, but because that doesn't always work, I iterate through the active processes using `psutil` and kill any with "EXCEL.EXE" for a process name. What ends up happening most of the time on my machine is that the application does not quit before it is killed (the code does not stop at `app.Quit()` and wait for shutdown before moving on). If I were to alter the code as is with an `else` block to not hunt through processes for Excel if the app is passed, I could not guarantee that Excel is shut down by the end of the function (which is the entire point of the function). The options for this seem to be:

1. What I chose, attempt to quit and confirm the kill by process hunting
2. Try quitting, and if that doesn't work in x amount of time go hunting for Excel processes still open, but that would be a significant performance hit and the code readability would drop
3. Don't bother quitting at all and just kill Excel processes from the onset

Again, I felt that the 1st option was the best balance.

And that's about it. Any suggestions or critiques here would be greatly appreciated, or feel free to send a PR directly to the GitHub. Below is the heart of the project; the main module for functionality, and home to the function I'm focusing on above. Feel free to comment on anything else in this module / project too!

```
# Copyright (c) 2020 safexl
from contextlib import contextmanager
import psutil
import pythoncom
import win32com.client
EXCEL_PROCESS_NAME = "EXCEL.EXE"

__all__ = [
    'is_excel_open',
    'kill_all_instances_of_excel',
    'close_workbooks',
    'see_excel',
    'workbooks_currently_open',
    'last_row',
    'last_column',
    'worksheet_name_sanitization',
    'application',
]


def is_excel_open() -> bool:
    """
    Simple wrapper around `psutil.process_iter()` searching for individual processes of EXCEL.EXE
    :return: bool - Indicating whether or not Excel is open
    """
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == EXCEL_PROCESS_NAME:
                return True
        except psutil.AccessDenied:
            pass
    return False


def excel_open_files() -> list:
    """
    Simple wrapper around `psutil.process_iter()` searching for individual processes of EXCEL.EXE and returning
    all the filepaths of the open files. Used here only for testing purposes, when an `app` object cannot
    necessarily be passed as well, as is the case with `workbooks_currently_open`.
    :return: list - Full of filepaths, including all open files, addin files, etc. Note that prior to saving a file it is
                    given a .tmp filepath.
    """
    result = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == EXCEL_PROCESS_NAME:
                result.extend([popenfile.path for popenfile in proc.open_files()])
        except psutil.AccessDenied:
            pass
    return result


def kill_all_instances_of_excel(app: 'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")' = None) -> None:
    """
    Simple wrapper around `psutil.process_iter()` searching for individual processes of EXCEL.EXE, and killing each one it finds
    :param app: Optional win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") - Programmatic access to Excel application object
    :return: None
    """
    if app:
        # If application is passed, try to shut it down peacefully first
        close_workbooks(app, app.Workbooks)
        app.Quit()
        del app

    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == EXCEL_PROCESS_NAME:
                proc.kill()
        except (psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.NoSuchProcess):
            # passing on psutil.NoSuchProcess avoids erroring out if race conditions
            # close Excel *between* finding it and killing it with psutil
            pass


def new_workbooks(app: 'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")', workbooks_open_at_onset: iter) -> list:
    """
    Determines which workbooks are open currently in comparison to list of `workbooks_open_at_onset`, returns the delta
    :param app: win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") - Programmatic access to Excel application object
    :param workbooks_open_at_onset: iterable - Full of workbook COM objects that you want to close without saving
    :return: iterable - Full of workbook COM objects that are both open currently and not present in your `workbooks_open_at_onset`
    """
    paths_for_workbooks_open_at_onset = set(wb.FullName for wb in workbooks_open_at_onset)

    currently_open_workbooks = workbooks_currently_open(app)
    paths_for_currently_open_workbooks = set(wb.FullName for wb in currently_open_workbooks)

    paths_for_new_workbooks = paths_for_currently_open_workbooks - paths_for_workbooks_open_at_onset
    return [wb for wb in currently_open_workbooks if wb.FullName in paths_for_new_workbooks]


def close_workbooks(app: 'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")', workbooks: iter) -> None:
    """
    Best practice pywin32 for close workbooks without saving
    :param app: win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") - Programmatic access to Excel application object
    :param workbooks: iterable - Full of workbook COM objects that you want to close without saving
    :return: None
    """
    for wb in workbooks:
        app.DisplayAlerts = 0
        wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)
        app.DisplayAlerts = 1


def see_excel(workbooks: iter, window_state: int) -> None:
    """
    Makes every window of every workbook passed visible, will ignore the PERSONAL workbook and anything else in your StartupPath
    :param workbooks: iterable - Full of workbook COM objects whose windows you wish to maximize, minimize, or normalize
    :param window_state: int - xl_constant for Window.WindowState, available options include:
                                 * safexl.xl_constants.xlMaximized = -4137
                                 * safexl.xl_constants.xlMinimized = -4140
                                 * safexl.xl_constants.xlNormal = -4143
    :return: None
    """
    for wb in workbooks:
        wb.Application.Visible = True

        # Ignore changing the visibility of any workbooks you have set to open in your StartupPath
        # such as the PERSONAL.XLSB
        if wb.Application.StartupPath in wb.FullName:
            continue

        for window in wb.Windows:
            window.Visible = True
            window.WindowState = window_state


def workbooks_currently_open(app: 'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")') -> list:
    """
    Turns 'win32com.client.CDispatch' returned by `app.Workbooks` into Python list
    :param app: win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") - Programmatic access to Excel application object
    :return: list - Full of workbook COM objects currently open in Excel. Note that prior to saving a file it is given a generic
                    non-path such as 'Book1', 'Book2', etc.
    """
    return [wb for wb in app.Workbooks]


def last_row(worksheet) -> int:
    """
    Quick way to determine the number of rows in a worksheet. Assumes that data is within the `CurrentRegion` of cell A1.
    :param worksheet: Excel Worksheet COM object, such as the one created by code like:
        app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        wb = app.Workbooks.Add()
        ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    :return: int - indicating the number of rows a worksheet is using up
    """
    return worksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count


def last_column(worksheet) -> int:
    """
    Quick way to determine the number of columns in a worksheet. Assumes that data is within the `CurrentRegion` of cell A1.
    :param worksheet: Excel Worksheet COM object, such as the one created by code like:
        app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        wb = app.Workbooks.Add()
        ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    :return: int - indicating the number of columns a worksheet is using up
    """
    return worksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count


def worksheet_name_sanitization(worksheet_name: str) -> str:
    """
    Tool to cleanse worksheet names of common problems
    :param worksheet_name: str - String of name you're about to assign to a worksheet
    :return: str - String that won't cause an error when assigned to a worksheet. Note this function will throw an error
                   itself if the result of removing the invalid worksheet name characters leaves you with an empty string only
    """
    for char in ("\\", "/", "*", "[", "]", ":", "?"):
        worksheet_name = worksheet_name.replace(char, "")
    if not worksheet_name:
        raise ExcelError("Worksheet name cannot be empty string")
    return worksheet_name[:31]


@contextmanager
def application(
        kill_after: bool,
        maximize: bool = True,
        include_addins: bool = False,
) -> 'win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")':
    """
    Wrapper for the pywin32 interface for handling programmatic access to the Excel Application from Python on Windows.
    This context-managed generator function will yield an Excel application COM object that is safer to use
    than a bare call to `win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")`.
    :param kill_after: bool - Programmatic access to Excel will be removed outside the `with` block, but this argument
                              designates whether you wish to close the actual application as well, or to leave it running
    :param maximize: Optional bool - Defaults to `True`. Specifies what you would like to happen with your application windows,
                                     whether you want to maximize them or minimize them. This bool is contingent upon both
                                     your selection for `kill_after` and whether you run into an error during your `with` block.
                                     If `kill_after=True` then the code that maximizes or minimizes your windows will never
                                     be run, and the same goes for if Python encounters an error prior to reaching the end
                                     of your `with` block. In that way, the following 4 code snippets will have the same effect:
                                         1.) with safexl.application(kill_after=True) as app:
                                                 pass
                                         2.) with safexl.application(kill_after=True, maximize=True) as app:
                                                 pass
                                         3.) with safexl.application(kill_after=True, maximize=False) as app:
                                                 pass
                                         3.) with safexl.application(kill_after=False) as app:
                                                 raise
    :param include_addins: Optional bool - Defaults to `False`. As a feature (read "bug") Excel will not automatically
                                           load/open your *installed & active* Excel addins when an instance is called from code,
                                           neither Python nor VBA, as discussed in the following links:
                                             * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213375/loading-addins-when-excel-is-instantiated-programmatically
                                             * https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/add-in-doesnt-load.849923/
                                           The `include_addins` parameter indicates whether you would like to include the addins
                                           you have previously set to 'Installed' to show up in the Excel instance created.
                                           Similar to the `maximize` parameter, if an error occurs in your `with` block, or if you
                                           set `kill_after=True` it doesn't matter what value `include_addins` is, as that part of
                                           the code will not be executed. Please note there is a performance hit taken by setting
                                           this parameter to `True`, especially if you or your user has many addins installed.
    :return: win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application") - Wrapped to follow best practices and clean up after itself
             Note, I specifically chose `Dispatch` over both `DispatchEx` and `EnsureDispatch` to avoid some odd bugs
             that can crop up with those methods, as discussed further on SO:
               * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648933/using-pywin32-what-is-the-difference-between-dispatch-and-dispatchex
               * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930751/autofilter-method-of-range-class-failed-dispatch-vs-ensuredispatch
    """
    open_at_onset = is_excel_open()
    pythoncom.CoInitialize()
    _app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    if open_at_onset:
        workbooks_open_at_onset = workbooks_currently_open(_app)
    else:
        workbooks_open_at_onset = []

    try:
        # For use inside a `with` block, with exceptions caught and cleaned up for you
        yield _app

    except Exception as e:
        err_msg = e

    else:
        err_msg = ""

    finally:
        workbooks_opened_during_with_block = new_workbooks(_app, workbooks_open_at_onset)
        if kill_after or err_msg:
            # If user wants to kill the app after the with block OR if an error occurs
            # close everything that was opened during this `with` block alone
            if workbooks_open_at_onset:
                # close newly created workbooks instead of killing the entire app
                close_workbooks(_app, workbooks_opened_during_with_block)
            else:
                # kill the app's entire presence on computer
                kill_all_instances_of_excel()
        else:
            # Excel Application oddity where addins are not visible on the ribbon even when installed
            # when app instance is created via code. Thankfully the `.Installed` attribute remains intact,
            # and to make your addins show up on the ribbon, you must turn the installed addins off and then on again...
            # See docstring for links describing the problem, this solution, and more details.
            if include_addins:
                for add_in in _app.AddIns:
                    if add_in.Installed:
                        add_in.Installed = False
                        add_in.Installed = True

            # Running `see_excel` at the end here
            # makes sure that no Excel instances are left running in the background
            # as it is still easy to forget to make everything visible before leaving
            # a successful `with` block
            if maximize:
                see_excel(workbooks_opened_during_with_block, -4137)  # xlMaximized
            else:
                see_excel(workbooks_opened_during_with_block, -4140)  # xlMinimized

        del _app
        pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
        if err_msg:
            raise ExcelError(err_msg)


class ExcelError(Exception):
    pass
```